# Construct list of strings in very specific order

Tags: c#

I need to construct a list of strings that are output in this order:
EXA - in bold text

EXD - in bold text

EXY - in bold text

EXZ - in bold text

COA - in bold text

COD - in bold text

COY - in bold text

COZ - in bold text

EXB

EXC

EXE

EXF

COB

COC

COE

COF

EXJ

EXK

COJ

COK

The "in bold text" represents a property on my view object called 'isBold' and tells my view to make these codes bold.

I need to guarantee that when my view is passed the list of these view objects they are ordered as listed above as i cant guarantee they will come back from my database in the correct order.

I can do something like

```
List<DeclarationTypeViewObject> e = m_ViewObject.AvailableDeclarationTypes.Where(x => x.Code.StartsWith("E") && x.IsBold).ToList();
            UpdateDeclarationTypeViewObject(e, declarationTypeViewObjects);

    List<DeclarationTypeViewObject> c = m_ViewObject.AvailableDeclarationTypes.Where(x => x.Code.StartsWith("C") && x.IsBold).ToList();
    UpdateDeclarationTypeViewObject(c, declarationTypeViewObjects);

 List<DeclarationTypeViewObject> cn = m_ViewObject.AvailableDeclarationTypes.Where(x => x.Code.StartsWith("E") && !x.IsBold).ToList();
        UpdateDeclarationTypeViewObject(cn, declarationTypeViewObjects);
```

And so on but this will get messy when I get to the un-bolded codes when trying to insert the codes starting with C in between the ones starting with E, plus this approach feels very 'hacky' and I'd like a more elegant way of achieving my desired result.

Comment: You can define the order in `DeclarationTypeViewObject` from a `Dictionary` based on the `code` value. With that you don't need any additional code

Comment: IMHO, your statement about the list being very "specific" is in fact "specific to your business/use case" (only) - meaning it's a "pattern" that only "you" define - doesn't really follow any "sort order" - hence you'll have to define/create it specifically

Comment: @Ross - Check the posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the definition of `DeclarationTypeViewObject` is as something like :

```
public class DeclarationTypeViewObject
{
    public string Code {get; set;}
    public bool IsBold {get; set;}
}
```

Which you change to add the `Order` property to get the order from a defined `Dictionary`. This can also be persisted in any storage (like database)

```
public static class DeclarationType
{
    public static Dictionary<string, int> Orders = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"EXA", 1},
        {"EXD", 2},
        {"EXY", 3},
        {"EXZ", 4},
        {"COA", 4},
        {"COD", 5},
        {"COY", 6},
        {"COZ", 7},
        {"EXB", 8},
        {"EXC", 9},
        {"EXE", 10},
        {"EXF", 11},
        {"COB", 12},
        {"COC", 13},
        {"COE", 14},
        {"COF", 15},
        {"EXJ", 16},
        {"EXK", 17},
        {"COJ", 18},
        {"COK", 19}
    };
}

public class DeclarationTypeViewObject
{
    public string Code {get; set;}
    public bool IsBold {get; set;}
    public int Order {get { return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.Code) && DeclarationType.ContainsKey(this.Code) ?  DeclarationType.Orders[this.Code] : 100; }}
}
```

Now to get the AvailableDeclarationTypes in right order, use the following method

```
List<DeclarationTypeViewObject> e = m_ViewObject.AvailableDeclarationTypes.Order(a => a.Order).ToList();
```

Note - If code not exist then code returns the order as 100; you can change it accordingly to return a const or thrown exception as per your business logic.